# how to reorder UICollectionViewCells section wise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i need the suggestion for reordering `UICollectionViewCell`s section view.

For example:

Section 0:

```
Cell0 (frame:10,10,40,40) (IndexPath item:0 section:0)
Cell1 (frame:10,10,40,80) (IndexPath item:1 section:0)
Cell2 (frame:10,10,40,120) (IndexPath item:2 section:0)
Cell3 (frame:10,10,40,160) (IndexPath item:3 section:0)
```

Section 1:

```
Cell0 (frame:10,10,40,40) (IndexPath item:0 section:1)
Cell1 (frame:10,10,40,80) (IndexPath item:1 section:1)
Cell2 (frame:10,10,40,120) (IndexPath item:2 section:1)
```

this the way i attached with `CollectionView`. So when is visible, the less height cells are behind the more height cell, its un visible.

So, after loading i need to reorder the `Cell` in this following way.

Section 0:

```
Cell3 (frame:10,10,40,160) (IndexPath item:0 section:0)
Cell2 (frame:10,10,40,120) (IndexPath item:1 section:0)
Cell1 (frame:10,10,40,80) (IndexPath item:2 section:0)
Cell0 (frame:10,10,40,40) (IndexPath item:3 section:0)
```

Section 1:

```
Cell2 (frame:10,10,40,120) (IndexPath item:0 section:1)
Cell1 (frame:10,10,40,80) (IndexPath item:1 section:1)
Cell0 (frame:10,10,40,40) (IndexPath item:2 section:1)
```

So, what is the best way to do this. Kindly suggestion. if need any clarification. comment it

Comment: Jst modify the order of the datasource then reload the collectionView.

Comment: can u explain little more with code....

Comment: How do you populate your collection view?

Comment: same which i mentioned in question, before reordering the cell. i am using flow layout for making custom layout cell.

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the `zIndex` of the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` returned by your layout... zIndex  determines the front-to-back ordering...

Comment: You probably want to read [this:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html)

Comment: @Allan,simply i need a collection view layout like `stacked layout`. Example: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial this layout behind cell are little bit rotated but i need in stacked way layout

Comment: @MikePollard Thanks you i got the solution with ur help...